# Complicated logic circuit drawing with Tikz - two input buffer gate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, logic, tikz-circuit-lib

i'm trying to draw similar image with Tikz and Circuit Library, so far i'm stucked at drawing buffer gate with two labeled inputs (IBUFGDS and IBUFDS), standard library have a gate with only one input...

Anyone have an idea how can i start?

Complete drawing is not necessary , i just need a hand:D

[image: LINK TO IMAGE]

So far i come up with somtheing like this, but it's just a start:P

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{circuitikz} \draw
 (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {IBUFDS}
    (opamp.+) node[left] {$data\ ser\ p$}
    (opamp.-) node[left] {$data\ ser\ n$}
    (opamp.out) node[right] {$data\ ser$}

 (0,-5) node[op amp] (opamp) {IBUFGDS}
    (opamp.+) node[left] {$clk\ in\ p$}
    (opamp.-) node[left] {$clk\ in\ n$}
    (opamp.out) node[right] {$clk\ in$}
;\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have already written so far? This way, you can get answers faster. Have a look at `circuitikz` package.

Comment: not too much:D I tried to add new circuit symbol but it's not working

Comment: how can i post a longer code sample in the comment?

Comment: Just edit your question and put your code sample in.

Comment: sure:D  *obligatory characters to exceed 15 limit*

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) or type `ctrl-k`

Comment: Use an opamp symbol instead of a buffer (see circuitikz symbols list).

Comment: Will this package `circuitikz` allow me draw whole picture? Or i will have to mix it with raw tikz?

Comment: Yes to both. I suggest that you convert your code snippet into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Ok, so using `opamp` from `circuitz` i came up with something like this (code in previous post). Now how to draw IODELAY box with labels placed like this?

[LINK TO IMAGE][1]


  [1]: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14052972/buffers_circuitikz.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with the labels in the operationals is that the point at which the label is centered is not at the right place. This can be easily spotted if you use a `\bullet` as label. It is not the "center" of the node either, as can be seen by drawing a red dot at (0,0):

```
\begin{circuitikz} 
\fill[red] (0,0) circle(2pt);
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$\bullet$}
    (opamp.+) node[left] {$data\ ser\ p$}
    (opamp.-) node[left] {$data\ ser\ n$}
    (opamp.out) node[right] {$data\ ser$}
;\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: Output]

So, the best option is to place a new node containing the label, positioned relative to the center of the operational (the red dot in the figure above). The left side of the operational is at 10mm from the red dot, so you can put your label at `(-9mm,0)`. Using the same amount in all your operationals ensures that all the inner labels are left aligned. The following code implements this idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{opamp label/.style={xshift=-9mm, font=\footnotesize,right}}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw
 (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.+)   node[left]        {$data\ ser\ p$}
    (opamp.-)   node[left]        {$data\ ser\ n$}
    (opamp.out) node[right]       {$data\ ser$}
    (opamp)     node[opamp label] {IBUFDS}

 (0,-3) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.+)   node[left]        {$clk\ in\ p$}
    (opamp.-)   node[left]        {$clk\ in\ n$}
    (opamp.out) node[right]       {$clk\ in$}
    (opamp)     node[opamp label] {IBUFGDS}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Result]

Comment: Great, thanks for help, what about arrow underneath the buffer, from the left right edge, like T_IOPI in the image on the first page