# Complicated Tikz logic drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, technical-drawing, logic

This is a follow-up to this question [Complicated logic circuit drawing with Tikz - two input buffer gate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84503/complicated-logic-circuit-drawing-with-tikz-two-input-buffer-gate)

Any ideas how can I draw this next element **IODELAY2**, should I use Resistance symbol?

For me syntax for connecting different symbols is really hard to understand, connecting logical and electrical elements seems impossible ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pragmatic shot based on JLDiaz' answer in the linked question : You can adjust further for your own taste

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{opamp label/.style={xshift=-9mm, font=\footnotesize,right}}
\tikzset{iovardelay/.style={label={[above]90:\textsf{#1}},
                            label={[right=2ex]180:\textsf{I}},
                            label={[left=3ex]0:\textsf{O}},
                            draw,fill=blue!10,
                            minimum width=1cm,
                            minimum height=2cm
                            }
        }
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw
 (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.+)   node[left]        {$data\ ser\ p$}
    (opamp.-)   node[left]        {$data\ ser\ n$}
    (opamp.out) node[right]       {$data\ ser$}
    (opamp)     node[opamp label] {IBUFDS}

 (0,-3) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.+)   node[left]        {$clk\ in\ p$}
    (opamp.-)   node[left]        {$clk\ in\ n$}
    (opamp.out) node[above right]       {$clk\ in$}
    (opamp)     node[opamp label] {IBUFGDS} (opamp.out) --
 (3,-3) node[iovardelay=IODELAY2] (mydelay) {}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]